# MVC PHP - Displaying error message

Tags: php, templates

Hi I am newbie in using MVC pattern.

In login controller I have

```
function run() {
    $result = $this->model->run();
    if ($result) {
        header('location: '. URL .'myaccount/index');
    } else {

        $this->view->msg = '<h2>User or password are not valid! Please try again!</h2>';
        $this->view->render('login/index'); 
    }
}
```

In my login view I have

```
    <div class="container">
   <?php echo $this->msg; ?>
      <form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo URL; ?>login/run" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address" autofocus required>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>

    </div>
```

In my mind this should work like this. User tries to login and if user or password are not valid the login form will be shown again and above it will display the following message: User or password are not valid! Please try again!

I am encountering the following error  Notice: Undefined property: View::$msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\views\login\index.php on line 2

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your view doesn't know $msg, you might have to call msg another way. Are you using a third party mvc framework? Try `<?php echo $msg ?>` or `{msg}` in your view instead.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Well - everything since the beginning. 1) Controllers should **never** handle any logic, but assign request parameters 2) Controllers should not render anything 3) There are no Models in MVC, but services 4) Leaking data encapsulation 5) Missing an abstraction for `$response`

Comment: You are using http header redirection to redirect to the view if you have not ran the setup includes then the second script won't have these objects loaded. Generally you would use require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] and the path to. By doing this you will still have access to the model inside the view.

Comment: @DaveJust 1) Controllers should never handle any logic, but assign request parameters -- What do you mean? Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: @AdrianGeorge http://r.je/mvc-in-php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can redirect like this `header('location: '. URL .'myaccount/index?error');` 
and check in the view if `$_GET['error']` is set echo the error.

:D stupid way but I think it will work